# Does will pagination work with forms which have method="POST"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I switched my advanced order form to POST from GET as the URI request became too large for browsers to handle. Everything works fine, with the exception of will pagaination. It keeps adding the page to the url itself `http://localhost:3000/orders/advanced_search` like `http://localhost:3000/orders/advanced_search?page=2` which fails as this is a post call, and not a get call.

Any way that it can just update the params[:page] but not do anything to the link?

I used to just call `<%= will_paginate @orders["order_items"] %>` which worked great when it was a GET call where

`@orders["order_items"] = @orders["order_items"].paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                                               :per_page => limit, :total_entries=>@orders["total"])`

What I want is simple, add it to params, but do not add it to the link.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer posted is wrong. will_paginate was NOT built to work with post requests.

Your choices to 'make' will_paginate work with post request include:

**writing some javascript to:**

- preventDefault on click of the will_paginate-generated link

> $(".pagination li a").click(function(e){
>   e.preventDefault(); ....

- find the target page via the clicked link.

(below code is assuming all will_paginate links have a query string...which they do. But note that this particular line of code won't work if you are passing in more params in the controller via the params option for will_paginate..which you shouldn't be in the first place because we are trying to achieve a post request.)

> var tp_id = $(this).attr("href").split('?page=')[1]

- generate a hidden input with the correct name attribute depending on the clicked will_paginate link.

> $('form').append("< input type='hidden' name='page' value='" + tp_id +"' >")

- finally post to the controller action of the search form.

> $('form').submit()

.done. I hope this puts you on the right path.

Comment: I hope it helps someone else....I am no longer even writing Rails code these days. From what I recall, we had to switch to Get for it to work. Anything exceeding the length has to be downloaded via a csv.

Comment: Just finished my implementation for advanced searches using  pagination, and even a total records per page input, all utilizing a post request using the snippets above as the basis of my implementation. (The ability to 'save' a given search (i.e., the filters that were chosen) was the real hard part via post request...I used to just save the url query string when it was a get!)

Comment: I've achieved it based on your idea with some minor changes required by my code.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a param to will_paginate

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation

```
<%= will_paginate @orders['order_items'], :params => { :method => :post } %>
```

If it doesn't work, set te complete controller and action to params.

Comment: I tried something like that....This is what it adds to the url now method=post&page=2

Comment: It's weird... I found a last solution for you, if you doesn't find better http://www.botvector.net/2008/08/willpaginate-on-ajax.html