# How can I make a POST call instead of GET call with will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

How can I make a post call instead of get call when i am paginating through pages using rails gem will_paginate?

In controller I have

```
@bills = Bill.where(some_condition)  # returns collection
@bills = @bills.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

In view have used a table structure and at the end, have used `<%will_paginate%>`, hence page 1 is showing up, but when I click on "next" or "page 2" then GET req. goes, I want to change it to POST call, is it possible?

Comment: If you trying to move between pages with post request you doing something wrong

Answer (score 2):

I agree with antiqe's comment it's not right to paginate through POST request.

But if you have made up your mind to use POST read below:

1. By modifying the will_paginate

   Source enchante's comment

   > use will_paginate doesn't support post by default, if you insist to use post, you need to customize LinkRender for will_paginate, see reference: github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Link-renderer
2. By custom POST requests

   From the [source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/will_paginate/S_F46cTpGT8):

   > the only correct way to do pagination in HTML would be to render a form inside which each pagination link is a submit button with the attribute name="page" set to page number as value. This form should also preserve existing search parameters, therefore it should have a hidden field for each of the current parameters. Clicking on the submit button will resubmit the advanced search with the page parameter changed.
3. By custom ajax request

   Or You can write a javascript to prevent the default get request on pagination links and send ajac post request instead. see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568179/does-will-pagination-work-with-forms-which-have-method-post)

The reason `will_paginate` don't support POST is that nobody uses it.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible. But not suggest to do so.

```
@bills = @bills.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Here the *params[:page]* controls which page should be shown, include *:page* parameter in the post, that should work.

Updated:

will_paginate doesn't support post by default, if you insist to use post, you need to customize LinkRender for will_paginate, see reference: github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Link-renderer

Comment: where would I change it, but?

Comment: will_paginate doesn't support post by default, if you insist to use post, you need to customize LinkRender for will_paginate, see reference: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Link-renderer