# Ruby on Rails: getting 404 not found error, when going to next page after search, using pg_search and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, pg-search

I'm facing a strange error, where going to next page after search will cause 404 not found error. But the pagination works well if I don't search.

routes.rb

```
resources :activities do
  post :search, on: :collection
end

match "/403", to: "errors#error_403", via: :all
match "/404", to: "errors#error_404", via: :all
match "/422", to: "errors#error_422", via: :all
match "/500", to: "errors#error_500", via: :all

get :ie_warning, to: 'errors#ie_warning'
get :javascript_warning, to: 'errors#javascript_warning'
get :pwreset, to: "pages#pwreset"
get :activities, to: "activities#index"
get :home, to: "pages#home"
root to: "pages#home"
```

controller.rb

```
@@page_size = 3
# GET /activities
def index
  @activities = Activity.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @@page_size)
end

# POST /products/search
def search
  if params[:search][:title].present?
    @activities = Activity.search_activities(params[:search][:title]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @@page_size)
    render :index
  else
    @activities = Activity.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @@page_size)
  end

end
```

html.haml

```
- @activities.each do |activity|
.row
  .col-md-8
    = link_to activity.title, activity
  .col-md-2
    %p= activity.publisher
  .col-md-2
    %p= activity.created_at.to_date

.force-to-bottom
  .text-center
    = will_paginate @activities


= simple_form_for :search, url: search_activities_path, method: :post do |f|

  .form-inline
    = f.input :title, label: false, placeholder: 'search...'

    = button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do
      %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search{"aria-hidden" => "true"}

    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
    = link_to 'clear filter', activities_path
```

error message

```
Started GET "/activities/search?page=2" for ::1 at 2018-04-16 04:39:57 +0100
Processing by ActivitiesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "id"=>"search"}
Activity Load (17.9ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering errors/error_404.html.haml within layouts/application
Haml::TempleEngine: Option :ugly is invalid
Rendered errors/error_404.html.haml within layouts/application (6.2ms)
Haml::TempleEngine: Option :ugly is invalid
Haml::TempleEngine: Option :ugly is invalid
Rendered layouts/_environment_notice.html.haml (2.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 245ms (Views: 162.2ms | ActiveRecord: 74.7ms)
```

any one can help please, I still really don't know what is going on with that error after a few hours of research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search the parameters are submitted via the POST method (`method: :post`). When you click next page you request the page via GET, however the browser does not send the search parameters via GET and there is no route `get :search` so the show action is used instead leading to the 404 page.

While it may be [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25300684/6058571) to make will_paginate use POST it is not recommended.

Cf. https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Simple-search :

> When you create a search form, *make sure* its method is `GET`
>
> ```
> <% form_tag request.path, :method => 'get' do %>
>   <% content_tag :label do %>
>     Search term:
>     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
>   <% end %>
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> If your form's action is POST (or any other HTTP method) then the
>   search term won't be applied to subsequent page links. In other words,
>   when you follow the "Next page" or any other page link, the search
>   parameter(s) would be lost.
>
> Search forms that post with GET are better practice, anyway. One of
>   immediate benefits is that users are able to bookmark search results.
>   Caching is another benefit: browsers, proxies, etc. are happy to cache
>   content that was a result of a GET request.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you explained very well ! so I just need to change my form method from post to get and also in the routes.rb ?and u mentioned there is no route get :search, how should i add the route ? im sorry, this is my first time using ruby on rails. my questions may be stuid

Answer (score 0):

post :search, on: :collection
But your request is get?

Comment: sorry, I don't get you. request is get is that because the will_paginate ?

Comment: You have declared 
resources :activities do
  post :search, on: :collection
end

/activities/search?page=2 link only for post request ..not for get request

Comment: resources :activities only: [:index] do
      collection do
        get :search, to: 'activities#search'
      end
    end

Comment: thank you, I just simply changed post to get in both routes.rb and html. and it starts working now.  But the url used to be /activities/search?page=2, now is /activities/search?utf8=✓&search[title]=d&button=. Can this be fixed ?